# VPN with Cisco AnyConnect, internet works on WIFI but not LAN

Tags: vpn, internet, ethernet, cisco-anyconnect

I can't connect to any servers or websites when I connect to my company's VPN when my network connection is etherne cable using Cisco AnyConnect.

Everything works fine when I connect using my WIFI and ethernet cable is disconnected.

When connected only to my LAN with an ethernet cable I can browse websites. But when I use Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my company's VPN the connection is established (Cisco window goes away as if it's connected) but I can't ssh to any servers and can't browse to any websites. It's as if all traffic is blocked.

I tried the [solution here](https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Features/5268AC-VPN-Problem/m-p/4875088#M9558) but still didn't work.
For my AT&T "Applications, Pinholes and DMZ" I configure a profile with these settings:

`Definition List
Protocol    Port (or Range) Host Port   Timeout (sec)   Action
udp         443             443         600 
tcp         443             443         600 
tcp         80              80          600 
udp         500             500         600 
udp         4500            4500        600`

My internet provider is AT&T.

Mac OS Mohave 10.14.6

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client v4.5.04029

(update)
Running ifconfig and looking for inet:

`VPN via WIFI:
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet 10.0.0.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet 172.28.25.144 --> 172.28.25.144 netmask 0xfffffc00 
VPN via LAN:
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet 192.168.1.108 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet 172.28.25.127 --> 172.28.25.127 netmask 0xfffffc00`

Comment: Is your LAN connection on the same subnet as the Company's VPN server?  Is the Wireless on a different subnet?  That would explain it.  Subnet is the third octet in 192.168.50.x   (subnet = .50 here)

Comment: John - How would I find my subnet? I ran ifconig and looked for inet. Update my post with that info.

Comment: Your Wireless appears to be 10. 0.0.25  and your Wired appears to be 192.168.1.108.  So the second Wired subnet is .1 .  Is your VPN server also 192.168.1.x?  The wireless address is completely different and that is probably why it is working well.